# Why does a process think he's the only one in memory?

Tags: process, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

In a software security course, I saw that the OS tells to each process that he is the only one to exist at the time, and so the process have the whole memory (RAM) available for him.

What are the reasons to design systems this way? 
If this is too wide a subject for a concise answer, a couple of leads to where this information is available will be much appreciated.

From a naive point of view, I would think it would be the source of many issues, such as for a process to think that he can ask to expand a lot more than what is actually possible.

Also, is this design common on all modern computing architectures?

I couldn't find how to find the answers on search engines.

Comment: There are too many decades of computer system design that lead to this architecture. The answer is probably in your textbook.

Comment: It's not in my textbook because I don't have one. If I could have found the answer on my own, I wouldn't have asked my question here.

Comment: Read about [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) and [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: @eryksun Thank you! I'm beginning to see the point of this architecture, mainly security.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement of O/S design is not correct.

For example, most modern system divide the address space into a user space and a system space. Each process has its own user space but all share the same system space.

The security challenge then is to protect the system space. A process can screw up its own user space, leaving everyone else intact. A process screwing up the system space does so to everyone.

One key to security is the paths from the user space into the system space.

That's just the memory protection. There are other holes a system can create in security.